# Is it possible to switch glycoprotein of viruses?

Tags: science-based, biology

Like take flu virus and switch its glycoprotein with measles?
On my world there is warfare and I want science to well fit the story.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as you can edit the part of the genetic code of the virus which the appropriate codes for the specific glycoprotein.

If you don't do so the second generation will be expressing the old ones.